# You cannot add a null=False column without a default value

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm adding a new app, and while setting up the database using South I get the following:

```
... line 11, in forwards
db.add_column('experiments_dailyreport', 'test_group_size', 
  orm['experiments.dailyreport:test_group_size'])

You cannot add a null=False column without a default value.
```

Given that this is a new table with no data in it, is there some way to force this migration?

Comment: you could provide a default empty value when migrating, is that an option you could consider?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I could do that if I was setting up the migration, but I'm not, I'm installing a package I just downloaded.

Comment: What is the name of the app? There may already be a fix for it on github or where they're hosted.

Comment: @SimeonVisser `django-lean`, I'm running the version `pip` installed, I can't find anything newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force a migration using:

```
manage.py migrate --fake django-lean 0005
```

where `0005` is the version number of the migration. All that matters in your situation are:

- having the correct database schema in the end
- having South think that all migrations have been run

After that you can run the other migrations as normal. Alternatively, you can remove South, create the latest tables from `django-lean` using `syncdb` and then fake all the `django-lean` migrations.

Lastly, if you're certain that there's something wrong with the migration, it's worth contacting the `django-lean` developer(s) about this.